# Share logic between resolvers and mutations in Apollo Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apollo-server

Here is my resolver file:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express'
import * as db from '../database'

export const typeDefs = gql`
    extend type Query {
        getFoos(): Foo
    }

    type Foo {
        id: ID!
        missingBar: [String]
    }

    input addBarInput {
        fooId: ID!
        barId: ID!
    }

    extend type Mutation {
        addBar(input: addBarInput): Foo
        startFoo(fooId: ID!): Foo
    }
`

export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        getFoos: async () => db.foo.findAll({include: [db.bar]}),
    },
    Foo: {
        missingBar: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
            // here starts the relevant part of code
            const someBarIds = await db.some_table.findAll({
                where: {bar_id: obj.bar_id},
            }).map(el => el.bar_id)

            const otherBarIds = await db.other_table.findAll({
                where: {id: obj.bars.map(b => b.id)},
            }).map(el => el.id)

            const missingBarIds = someBarIds.filter(x => !otherBarIds.includes(x));
            // here ends the relevant part of code

            return await db.instruments.findAll({where: {id: missingInstrumentsIds}}).map(instrument => instrument.name)
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
        addBar: async (prev, { input }) => {
            const foo = await db.foo.findByPk(input.fooId)

            const bar = await db.users.findByPk(input.userId)
            await bar.setBar(foo)

            return foo
        },
        startFoo: async (prev, { input }) => {
            const foo = await db.foo.findByPk(input.fooId)

            // here I would like to have the code from missingBar without copypasting it
            // then I need to do more logic (irrelevant for this question) using that missingBarIds array

            return foo
        },
    }
}
```

As a note, I don't think the precise Sequelize logic in the `missingBar` resolver is important to the core of the question so I simplified it. The gist of it is that I want to execute an update on the DB only if all the required elements have been added to `foo`, and that check is performed with the exact same logic as the one in the `missingBar` resolver.

Is there any way to share parts of the logic between different mutations and resolvers? Ideally, declaring a function somewhere and using it in both places?

This hypothetic function's only parameter in this case would be an instance of the `foo` object (which is a Sequelize model, but again I don't think that's really relevant in this case), and the return value would be that `missingBarIds` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, you can just write a function and use it in both resolvers. If you don't want to have it in the same module, put it in a different module and import it. There's nothing wrong with that.

That said, since you're using Sequelize, you can add both static and instance methods to your model class.

A static method would be written like this:

```
Foo.doSomething = function doSomething () {
  ...
}
```

and called using the model class:

```
Foo.doSomething()
```

An instance method would be written like this:

```
Foo.prototype.doSomething = function doSomething () {
  ...
}
```

and then called *on an instance of the class*:

```
const foo = await Foo.findOne()
foo.doSomething()
```

Note that when you define an instance method, as long as you don't use an arrow function, `this` will refer to the instance itself.